# Why does switching parent nodes not switch its children nodes?

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-tree

For example, in this question: https://leetcode.com/problems/invert-binary-tree/
The correct solution is:

```
 TreeNode* invertTree(TreeNode* root) {
        if(root!=NULL)
        {
            TreeNode* tmp = (root->left);
            root->left=root->right;
            root->right=tmp;
            invertTree(root->left);
            invertTree(root->right);
        }
        return root;
    }
```

However, why can we not just simply do:

```
TreeNode* invertTree(TreeNode* root) {
        if(root!=NULL)
        {
            TreeNode* tmp = (root->left);
            root->left=root->right;
            root->right=tmp;
        }
        return root;
    }
```

Wouldn't switching the parent nodes of the subtrees also switch its children?

Comment: You should really draw the tree as you step through with a debugger.

Comment: I did, but i thought that it would also switch the children, not just the selected nodes.

Answer (score 3):

Start with a tree (at least three levels):

```
      A
    /   \
  B       C
 / \     / \
D   E   F   G
```

Swap the left and right children of the root:

```
      A
    /   \
  C       B
 / \     / \
F   G   D   E
```

Notice that you are not yet at the inverted tree:

```
      A
    /   \
  C       B
 / \     / \
G   F   E   D
```

Answer (score 0):

Swapping the left and the right pointers only swaps the pointers, but the subtree pointers (further down) also have to be inverted. That's why you have to recurse down the left and right trees.